# Scanning available WiFi networks results in weird characters (Raspbian)

Tags: linux, encoding, command-line, utf-8, raspberry-pi

Doing a `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID` on the command line of RPi 3 and I get all the available WiFi ESSIDs.  However, anything with an apostrophe results in:

> ESSID:"Ryan\xE2\x80\x99s iPhone"

Is there a way to encode the output of this command so it doesn't produce those characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use e.g.

```
echo -e $(sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID)
```

The `echo -e` part will unescape the characters e.g. havging `\xXX`.

Note: this seems shell and version dependent.